# Overriding all terminate actions on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm fairly new to Eclipse plugin development and I currently need to override the action of all terminate actions in the IDE. So far I have found them in the Run Menu, processConsole context menu and view, Debug view context menu and toolbar, and the main IDE toolbar.

From my research I tried to override the handler but that seems to achieve nothing

```
      <handler
            class="dummyterminateoverrideplugin.handlers.TerminateHandler"
            commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate">
      </handler>
      <handler
            class="dummyterminateoverrideplugin.handlers.TerminateHandler"
            commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.TerminateAll">
      </handler>
      <handler
            class="dummyterminateoverrideplugin.handlers.TerminateHandler"
            commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.TerminateAndRelaunch">
      </handler>
```

I also tried to add always true enabledWhen and activeWhen conditions but the default handler always gets called

This is my class, the content of the execute function is of course not what I'm currently aiming towards

```
public class TerminateHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "DummyTerminateOverridePlugin",
                "Hello, Eclipse world");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to override the terminate handler? Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to achieve my goal of overriding the terminate actions, even if it requires more work or changing actions one by one (ex. Listeners, hiding eclipse buttons and replacing them with my own, etc..)

Thank you

Comment: What's your root problem (the X of this [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))?

Comment: My root problem is trying to override the terminate action and failing, if that makes sense.
Edit: I think what you're asking is what I'm trying to achieve? If that is true, I need to run my own terminator @howlger

Comment: Please describe what problem you like to solve with this from the user's point of view. Be aware, that you talk about a general platform command. For example, JDT is based on the platform's debug framework to debug Java application, CDT does the same for C/C++, PDT for PHP, etc. Are you sure you want to change the behavior for all these languages? For what and why do you need specific terminate handling?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea, I wouldn't let a plug-in that tried to do this anywhere near my Eclipse. So, as already asked, why do you think you need to do  this?

Comment: @howlger I understand your concern and it is by no means misplaced. My application however is very specific and although it could be used in all the cases mentioned it is not developed for them. In the end there is a buffer I need to flush before the termination can take place. I was able to resolve the issue in another plugin with it's own custom terminate button. I was hoping I could do the same with the other default terminate buttons.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand what I want to do is unconventional, but so far I have been unable to achieve what was written in the previous comment otherwise hence my decision to try and replicate my action in the other terminate buttons. Do you perhaps have extra knowledge that could solve my issue without my solution?

Comment: Eclipse is an extensible platform, even if you don't use it as such. If you want to change the termination behavior of something specific, you are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @howlger Unfortunately not an option, I'm building on a 10yo+ application. I just saw this 20yo [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016) that I believe might be the culprit but I can't seem to find a good way to capture signals in my case

Comment: @RoxelX Shutdown hooks are executed on exiting Eclipse (e.g. on _File > Exit_). The Eclipse platform has moved to GitHub long time ago, not using bugs.eclipse.org anymore. If you don't want to change the behavior of everything that uses the debug framework of the Eclipse platform including JDT, CDT, PDT, etc. (which is more than questionable, as it does not make sense), you are looking at the wrong place. You talk about termination without saying what is to be terminated.

Comment: @howlger If changing the behavior of everything will resolve the issue then I would be more than glad to at least try and take the risk to see the outcome. I'm unable to provide what exactly is to be terminated but I believe the main risk in my app would be changing the CDT, other than that we have the custom framework with its own terminate button where the issue was resolved and normally the tool shouldn't be used for much else

Comment: So basically, I have eclipse with plugins, **the tool in question**, running. I want to debug certain tests on that tool which provides some data that are flushed by the end of the test running, **basically the whole reason the tool exists.** BUT if I end up terminating the debug session using any default terminate button, **context menus, main menus, toolbars, etc**, the data output is corrupt and is uselss

Comment: Okay, then just change the behavior of terminating that specific tool rather than trying to change the general behavior of the general (language/tool independent) debug framework.